# C# MySQL transactions not working

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I want to understand how transaction works and I think I'm missing something.
I want to start adding some rows in the loop and when `i == 5` I want to rollback the transactions.

The main issue is that it doesn't rollback.

```
MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=;database=dbtest;");
conn2.Open();
MySqlCommand command2 = conn2.CreateCommand();
MySqlTransaction trans;
trans = conn2.BeginTransaction();
command2.Transaction = trans;

try
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('1','1','1')";
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (i == 5)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    trans.Rollback();
}
```

I tried adding `SET autocommit = 0` and `trans.Commit()` in various places but it still didn't work.

Then I decided to try on the MySQL database:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('1','1','1')
//also with COMMIT here
ROLLBACK;
```

It doesn't work either. I tried reading various tutorials, I checked the official MySQL page for transactions but still no progress.

Comment: If it isn't working on the MySQL database either, then there is probably some configuration issue on the server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are using de MyISAM engine that does not support transactions.
If that's the case you can try change it to InnoDB.